# Why is my django form sending as a GET and then giving a 405 error at POST

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I am trying to create a 'change email' form in Django. The form is showing in the template but when I submit the form this happens in the terminal

```
[09/Feb/2016 09:19:55] "GET /change_email/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3775
[09/Feb/2016 09:19:55] "GET /static/css/styles.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[09/Feb/2016 09:20:09] "POST /account/ HTTP/1.1" 405 0
```

And it sends to a blank page. I've also looked in the view and noticed, with some print statements, that it's going to the last else statement rather than going through `if request.POST:`

Here's my code:

View:

```
def change_email(request):
    if request.POST:
        print "POST"
        form = ChangeEmailForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            email = request.POST['current_email']
            email_new = request.POST['new_email']
            email_confirmed = request.POST['confirm_email']
            form.save()
            if email_new == email_confirmed:
                User.objects.get(email=email).update(email=request.POST['new_email'])
            else:
                return HttpResponse("These emails don't match")
        else:
            return render(request, 'registration/email_change_form.html', {'form': form})
    else:
        print "GET"
        form = ChangeEmailForm()
        return render(request, 'registration/email_change_form.html', {'form': form})
```

Form:

```
class ChangeEmailForm(forms.ModelForm):
    current_email = forms.EmailField()
    new_email = forms.EmailField()
    confirm_email = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('current_email', 'new_email', 'confirm_email')
```

Template:

```
<form action="{% url 'account' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Current Email">Current Email:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            {% render_field form.current_email type="email" class+="form-control" placeholder="Current Email" %}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
         <label for="New Email">New Email:</label>
         <div class="col-sm-10">
             {% render_field form.new_email type="email" class+="form-control" placeholder="New Email" %}
         </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
         <label for="Confirm New Email">Confirm New Email:</label>
         <div class="col-sm-10">
             {% render_field form.confirm_email type="email" class+="form-control" placeholder="Confirm New Email" %}
         </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" style="padding-top: 40px; text-align:right">
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
     </div>
 </form>
```

URLs:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^change_email/$', views.change_email, name="change_email"),
    url(r'^account/$',  TemplateView.as_view(template_name='account_details.html'), name="account"),    
]
```

Comment: Show us your `urls.py`, please.

Comment: 405 is Method Not Allowed, which isn't coming from the view you've posted. It's also suspicious that your form is posting to the url 'account', whereas the view is called 'change_email'. Are you sure this is the right view?

Comment: This is my urls.py: `urlpatterns = [ url(r'^change_email/$', views.change_email, name="change_email"),
     url(r'^account/$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='account_details.html'), name="account"), ]`

Comment: Sorry, I've added it now

Comment: side note, it's safer to use the escaped data: email = form.cleaned_data['current_email']

Comment: @DanielRoseman Yes, you are right. I've changed the posting url to `change_email` and it's now posting and giving an error which is relating to the query in the view. So this is progress, thank you.

Comment: @AviahLaor Ok, thank you. I will do.

Answer (score 0):

```
form action=""
```

This will send the form back to the change_email and go through the POST method part (currently it sends to another url). Also, use

```
if request.method == 'POST':
```

Answer (score 0):

`TemplateView` will not have `post` method defined. It is a basic class which makes template rendering easy.

Django will throw `405 METHOD NOT ALLOWED` on class based views if appropriated method is not defined for corresponding HTTP verb.

You should implement your own class:

```
class AccountView(TemplateView):
    template_name='account_details.html'

    def post(self):
        # your code to handle HTTP post
        # return response

    def get(self):
        # your code to handle HTTP get
        # return response
```

and in urlpatterns:

```
url(r'^account/$',  AccountView.as_view()),
```

More information at : https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/class-based-views/